# Screen flicker on mouse scroll

Tags: 12.04, screen, flicker

When i log in, everything works well for 5 minutes, then there is blank screen for 2 sec and again the display comes on the monitor but after that, the screen starts flickering on mouse scroll and the system becomes too slow.

I have found a workaround :  I go to sys setting >display and change to the lower resolution and on the confirmation screen I choose 'restore previous configuration' and again everything starts working normally.

But this has become a ritual of sort for me.  Is there a permanent resolution for this?